# How to call python dir value in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

How to call python dictionary value in javascript file?

my java script code is

```
 <script>
    var _data = {};
    var _data = how to Store value ??,
 </script>
```

My python code is

```
drives_a = [chr(x) + ':' for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]
list_with_tuples = [(x, x) for x in drives_a]
```

Comment: There is absolutely no way to answer this question. What is the relationship between the Python and JS code? How is the data getting from one to the other?

Comment: The question does not make any sense. Please think, write, read and then post the problem.

Comment: Well there are a few ways.. However python is mostly used server side and javascript client side. So you could work with ajax calls. You can also check out http://www.skulpt.org/, which let you use python kinda as u use JS without any server side support. If this is the answer you're looking for, I will expand in a full answer

Answer (score 0):

Which web framework do you use? Django?

If it is django then:

First dump to json the data in your view:

```
your_data  = __import__("json").dumps(your_python_dict_list_etc)
return render (request, "your_template.html", {"your_data":your_data})
```

Then you can use it like this in your template:

```
 <script>
    var json_data = {{ your_data }};
 </script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work even if it were django. You should add a comment if needed

Comment: Sorry, you are right, here you cannot use __import__. you need to import the json in the view. I edit it.

Comment: ye i am using Django but this script not working  .<script>
    var _data = {{ __import__("json").dumps(your_python_dict_list_etc) }};
 </script>

Comment: Do you have any idea how to  How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django, simple djanjo form

Comment: Use django forms. Maybe this link will be useful for you: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html